# Mysql Joining different tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `posts`, and `actions`

```
===================================
id  text
===================================
1   hello
2   hi
3   bye

===================================
post_id user
===================================
1       arthur
1       amanda
1       alex
2       mark
3       john
3       maria
```

result needs to be all from first table + count of results of second

```
===================================
id  text   count_users
===================================
1   hello  3
2   hi     1
3   bye    2
```

Is it possible? Sorry if I was stupid!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.text, COUNT(*)
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN users ON users.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id, posts.text
```

EDIT: Maybe you should think about adding a users table with only id_user and name. And add a third table with post_id and user_id

Answer (score 0):

The query you want is a basic `join` with `group by` query:

```
select p.id, p.text, count(*) as count_users
from posts p join
     actions a
     on p.id = a.post_id
group by p.id, p.text;
```

If you want all `posts`, even those with no actions, then you would modify the query to use a `left join`.